# Contribution pages fail after WP upgrade to 5.5

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, upgrade

Our previously smooth running membership sign-up process failed leaving me scratching my head after a WP upgrade to 5.5.
I had made some changes to the form at the same time and was blaming myself for a silly misconfiguration  rather than blaming the upgrade. Reverting to a back up that still had wp at 5.4 has solved the issue for now.
Anybody seen similar, got a solution?

Got this on the WP site health dashboard

> **An active PHP session was detected.**
>
> A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This
> interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be
> closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress made changes in v 5.5 that will cause any version of CiviCRM before 5.26 to break.  Details are in this post.  https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice

You will need to upgrade CiviCRM before WP.